# Permission denied when excute a script?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, lts

I run this script  **`./make.py`**  and it shows error **`bash: ./make.py: Permission denied`**

How to solve this?

Comment: sudo chmod +x make.py

Comment: You can `chmod` without `sudo` unless you get an error and you don't normally need `sudo` to run `make` unless you get an error. However, most of the time, you do need `sudo` to run `make install`.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code :**

```
chmod +x ./make.py
```

Comment: what is the bootstrap modifier after ./make.py.

Comment: does the above command do the same thing as "./make.py bootstrap"??

Comment: what is the name of the script

Comment: what do u mean by script?? @nux

Comment: ./ means you want to run a script , the name after it is the name of the script , a script contain commands to be executed together , just see the name and replace ./make.py , you should make the script executable , hope you understand

Comment: Keep in mind that `+x` allows everyone to execute the script.

Comment: @user240938 What you're trying to do is run `make.py` as an executable script.  In order for this to function, you have to give it the executable bit, which is what this chmod command does.  The alternative is to do `python make.py bootstrap`.  In the same command, though, `./make.py bootstrap`, `bootstrap` is just an argument being passed to `make.py` while it executes, so you still have to mark `make.py` as executable.

Comment: thnx guys i was able to change the permission by opening the properties of the file and graphically changed it

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this graphically (with most file managers) if that would be preferable to you. You could open the properties of the file by right-clicking it, then make sure that it is executable for your user.